# Azure Data Factory Get Copy

Tags: get, azure-data-factory

I am trying to make a call in ADF that works in my powershell.

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://host/allocatedRange' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Host: host' --header 'Content-Length: 20' --data '{"startNumber": "1"}'
```

Now when I try the same thing in ADF I get a 500 error.

```
{
    "source": {
        "type": "JsonSource",
        "storeSettings": {
            "type": "HttpReadSettings",
            "requestMethod": "GET",
            "additionalHeaders": "Content-Type: application/json ,\nHost: host ,\nContent-Length: 20",
            "requestBody": "{\"startNumber\": \"1\"}",
            "requestTimeout": ""
        },
        "formatSettings": {
            "type": "JsonReadSettings"
        }
    },
    "sink": {
        "type": "AzureSqlSink",
        "writeBehavior": "insert",
        "sqlWriterUseTableLock": false
    },
    "enableStaging": false
}
```

The expected return is

```
[{"order":"1","productNumber":"1234","originalQty":3.000000,"allocQty":3.000000,"allocDate":"2023-08-10T00:00:00","allocTime":"13:04","location":"","userId":"user"}]
```

Comment: what activity are you using to make the above get request? Can you show the error image for better understanding?

Comment: It is not passing the request body if I run this call using curl it sends the body in the call

Comment: what is it giving with web activity? Did you try the workaround that I have given below?

Comment: I had the api developer change the call to a post as you can't send a body with a get in ADF

Answer (score 0):

> Now when I try the same thing in ADF I get a 500 error

The below might be the reasons for the above error.

- Time out issue
- Firewall or permission issues at client server.

I suggest you publish and retry the same to check whether it results same or not. Check the similar [Ask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1002533/data-factory-synapse-copy-data-activity-failing-wi) by @[AnnuKumari-MSFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/users/na/?userid=43d447e6-d706-4a7e-a763-ba39c10a9f74).

If still results same, use other activities like web activity as a workaround in ADF to get the JSON. If it works, then the problem is with HTTP linked service. Use script activity SQL script with [`openjson()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) after web activity to insert the JSON into required table like below.

[image]